# How to start with ANTLR on Windows and VS 2010 generating C

Tags: c, windows, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I searched the web for while but did not found any good information how to start with ANTLR in a Windows environment using Visual Studio 2010. I target the C output option of ANTLR.

Thus, I am looking for a good tutorial/introduction how to get started with ANTLR on Windows, e.g. generate the *.c and *.h files and create a small VS2010 C project which walks the abstract syntrax tree (AST) produced by the ANTLR files and print it out to the console.

Any hints to a good tutorial/introduction would be very helpful for me!

Thanks in advance!
Bye, Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first time you learn ANTLR or you have at least used it for Java?

As ANTLR is Java centric, I personally suggest you learn it in Java/Eclipse environment first to make sure that you know the ABCs.

http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut/

Then you can learn about its VS integration. Personally I use the ANTLR MSBuild targets, which is part of ANTLR C# runtime to generate C# files from ANTLR grammar. You can easily do the same for C.